# Error during addView in MVC project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When I click to "AddView" in my MVC project, Visual Studio 2019 show me error "The Templates\PackageVersions5.2.5.xml file is missing from the installed template folder."
What I am missing in my installation?

Comment: I found solution here: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1421568/vs2019-while-adding-new-view-getting-erro-the-templates-packageversions5-2-6-xm)

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed with the Visual Studio Update 16.0.3

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.0.3

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the 50 Rep to comment so I'm adding this in the Answers section in the hopes that it will flesh out the issue some of us are having a bit.  I'm not sure if my problem resulting in the same error was created the same way Vlada's is but here is more information.

I to am having this issue.  I just uninstalled 2019 community and installed 2019 Professional this morning and while I had no issues with community, I am having this error now with Professional.

I opened an MVC 4 project I'm working on, 
Right clicked on one of the folders under Views 
Clicked Add 
Then clicked View

Filled out the pop up to Add View with a name and Empty (without model) for template
Checked Create as a partial view
clicked Add

and got the Following Error message

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The
>   Templates\PackageVersions5.2.6.xml file is missing from the installed
>   template folder.'

Fix for this is when you open your project in VS 2019, don't forget to

> 1. Right click on References
> 2. Manage NuGet Packages
> 3. Click the Updates tab
> 4. Update your NuGet packages to the most recent version that IS NOT a preview or beta.
> 5. Save all
> 6. Close Solution
> 7. Reopen the solution or project and continue where you left off.

[VS 2019 Professional Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaJM7.png)

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was updating the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` Nuget package (and its dependencies) to 5.2.7

Comment: When manipulating project and solution files, one of the steps removed the reference to the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc package, so re-installing it fixed the situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Go to the path in your PC**(*Visual Studio Template Path*)

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\vname\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates*

here **vname** is the version name of your installed Visual Studio like Professional or Community or Enterprise. After that check which PackageVersions(sequentially) is missing in this directory. In this case **PackageVersions5.2.5.xml** is missing here. I've resolve this issue by copied the **PackageVersions5.2.6.xml** and forcefully pasted in the same directory. After that I renamed the **PackageVersions5.2.6 - Copy.xml** file to **PackageVersions5.2.5.xml** and reopen the Visual Studio 2019 and it's worked.

[Image of the missing package versions in the template directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKgR1.png)